# How to get Connection id from user id inside signalr hub

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a signalr hub with a function like this

```
public void SendSurveyNote(int surveyId,List<string> users){}
```

Here I want to add all users of the list into a group `"Survey_" + surveyId` Then sending the group a message. But I only have the user id but joining a group requires a connection id. So how could I manage that.
Also I wonder would it be a performance issue to send each user a message without a group?

I call the function above when I add a new Survey like this

```
private static HubConnection hubConnection = new HubConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseUrl"]);
private static IHubProxy hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("myHub");
await hubConnection.Start();
hubProxy.Invoke("SendSurveyNote", model.Id, users);
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have access to the connection ID within `Context`. You'll want to establish groups within `OnConnected`. Observe the following implementation on your hub, where we will call it `MyHub`. We'll also group by `Context.User.Identity.Name` to establish a unique group per user, but this could be any value you wish to group by.

```
public class MyHub: Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, Context.User.Identity.Name)

        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

See [Working with Groups in SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups) for more information

Comment: Thank you, that helps. But the other part of the question _Would it be a performance problem to send each user his own message?_

Comment: I would define a client method, which your server method `SendSurveyNote` would invoke - which then again queries the server for whatever you wish to dish down. This reverses the processing to users who are currently connected to make the request on their own. This is likely the ideal approach you will wish to take.

Comment: That's what I am going to do. My message will stimulate the client to get unread notifications from the server. But my question about the stimulation message to be sent for each user or to the whole group? What is the best?

Comment: It all depends on what you have access to. I was under the impression the users were in a 1:1 grouping and you were calling them by their `Context.User.Identity`. If so, you'll only be stimulating users to query their updates in a unique sense. There will be no "whole group" though its misleading to use the term group. We have to do it this was in SignalR to send messages to specific users - even if they are in a group on their own. Make sense? Please let me know - I can keep working through suggestions with you

Comment: Thank you @sal. I really do not know how groups work and this is my first signalr project. As I told the message will not contain any data just telling the clients to request updates from the server. So I understand that the group is not more than a categorization of the connections? And when sending a message to a group it will send one per user?

Comment: If you group by the Identity, yes.. You'll have isolate groups with one user since each user has only one ID. I think you'll be on the right path with this!